# Pybluez RFCOMM server on Linux no advertisable service

Tags: linux, raspbian, rfcomm, pybluez

I am trying to run a very simple bluetooth server on Raspbian Linux. If it makes any difference I am using a Raspberry Pi 3's bluetooth adapter as opposed to a dongle.

```
from bluetooth import *

server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer",
               service_id = uuid,
               service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
               profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ], 
#                   protocols = [ OBEX_UUID ] 
                )

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)

try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0: break
        print("received [%s]" % data)
except IOError:
    pass

print("disconnected")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("all done")
```

When ran the following error is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rfcomm-server.py", line 15, in <module>
    profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ], 
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 268, in    advertise_service
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error no advertisable device.
```

I've seen a lot of people use this exact code so I'm kind of surprised I haven't found any mention of this specific issue. Also the client version of this works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Enable "Enable Page and Inquiry scan" by below command:

```
$ hciconfig hciX piscan
```

Comment: Thanks, I should mention I figured this out last year. It turns out I didn't have a Serial Port Profile and needed to run the daemon in compatibility mode. For anyone else looking, the answer can be found here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=133263